# Grepping lines which have range of number

Tags: grep, vim, numeric-data

I have few lines in my text file as below. I want to grep all the lines which have patterns like `:100`, `:101` and `:102` up to `:199` . How to get those lines instead of searching like this. `:100\|:101\|:102`...

```
abcd fhijk:123
abcd fhijk:124
abcd fhijk:174
abcd fhijk:225
```

Comment: May I ask the relevance of the `vim` tag on this question?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your numbers are always positive integers with no unit, unary plus signs or other decorations.

Regular expressions aren't great for comparing numbers, but if you see your input data as two `:`-separated columns, it would be easier to handle it with `awk`:

```
awk -F ':' '$2 >= 100 && $2 <= 199' <file
```

This would compare the second `:`-separated field in the data to 100 and 199 and print the complete line if the number is within the given range.

It's also doable with `grep`, but not as flexible:

```
grep ':1[0-9][0-9]$' <file
```

The expression `[0-9]` matches a single character between `0` and `9`. The `$` anchors the expression to the end of the line.

If you wanted to match lines with the numbers 100 to 250, you would just change `199` in the `awk` code to `250`, but with a regular expression you would have to come up with

```
grep -E ':(1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|250)$' <file
```

Here, the three parts of the parenthesis matches numbers from 100 to 199, then from 200 to 249, and lastly 250. (I say "numbers", but regular expressions always operate on *strings*).

Comment: Note: the `awk` one would match on `00120`,  `any:1000%` and may or may not match on `0.1e3` or `any:1000\r` depending on the `awk` implementation, which may or may not be a problem depending on how tamed the user input is. See also `awk -F ':' '$2+0 >= 100 && $2+0 <= 199'` to force numeric conversion of the 2nd field.